# How do I get a date column in the "20130627T100000" format?

Tags: sql-server

I need to format a datetime column from

```
2008-04-28 03:00:00.000
```

to

```
20080428T030000
```

How to get this format? Is there a built-in function for this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before SQL Server 2012:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(19), MyDateTimeCol, 126), ':', ''), '-', '')
```

SQL Server 2012

```
FORMAT(@MyDateTimeCol, 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss')
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it, out of curiosity, what would be the syntax for 2012 ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about a function that accepts a format string. But you can use the functions to extract the time and date parts. This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) should give you all the necessary hints. More precisely this [part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetDateandTimeParts).

I see though no time part (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) extraction, so in that case, `SUBSTRING` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DatePart` function to remove each individual element of the date (dd=day, yy=year etc.) and concatenate the outputs into the required format.

The arguments for DatePart can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).